# Calling native method from webview2

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I am trying to achieve similar functionality of `WebView.AddWebAllowedObject(String, Object)` from UWP webview in **webview2** for **WPF** application.

In documentation this method was found `AddHostObjectToScrip`. I am calling this method as `webView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("NativeObject", new WebJsObject());` from `NavigationStarting` event.  I have added my class like below:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class WebJsObject
{
    public WebJsObject()
    {
    }

    public void OnReady(string id)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"value received {id}");
    }
}
```

But in web debugging console, I don't find the **NativeObject**. What I am doing wrong here. How to do it right way for **webview2** in **WPF**?

Answer (score 0):

The host object is actually added in the script. Execute native method from script by
`window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.NativeObject.onReady();`